Arranging numbers into boxes given an inequality
In how many ways can the numbers $1$ through $5$ be entered once each into the five boxes below so that all the given inequalities are true?
$\boxed{\phantom{X}} < \boxed{\phantom{X}} > \boxed{\phantom{X}} < \boxed{\phantom{X}} > \boxed{\phantom{X}}$
Boxes 2 and 4 have to be two of the 3 biggest numbers from 1 to 5 (which is 3, 4 and 5) and boxes 1, 3, and 5 can be the rest of the numbers (1 and. There are 2! ways to place 4 and 5 in boxes 2 and 4 (4 can be in box 2 and 5 can be in box 4 and vice versa). Can someone help me finish solving this question?
A sample can be:
$\boxed{3} < \boxed{4} > \boxed{2} < \boxed{5} > \boxed{1}$

$1 < 3 > 2 < 5 > 4$, so your assumption that “Boxes 2 and 4 have to be the 2 biggest numbers” is wrong.

I think , brute force with some easy logical considerations is the best we can do here. We know for example that neither the first nor the last entry can be a five.

Also , if you have a solution , you can reverse the permutation and have a solution again. This symmetry is very helpful for an efficient enumeration.

Very similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4012503/42969

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_permutation

I figured it out! Thanks for your feedback.
